# Check if element is in user sight vertically

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking for a function that would get an element from the DOM and determine whether it is in the sight of the user vertically?

Comment: If you're going to post a question which you want to answer yourself (and there's no reason that you shouldn't), please rephrase so there is a clear question to be answered, and a clear problem is defined; and then post the answer *as* an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a function that would get an element and check if it is in the current scroll height the user is viewing. I ended up trying a bunch of functions that didn't quite do what I needed and I built my own. Since I didn't find such function I'm now sharing it with you guys in case someone needs it in future! `:P` This is without using any frameworks or plugins.

```
function visible(a, t){
    // a => element
    // t => tolerance, how much pixels can be hidden and still return true
    var w_top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        w_hgh = window.outerHeight,
        a_top = 0,
        a_hgh = a.offsetHeight;

    while(a.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
        a_top += a.offsetTop;
        a = a.offsetParent;
    }

    var b = (w_top + w_hgh) - (a_top + a_hgh);

    if(b > (0 - t) && b < (w_hgh - a_hgh + t)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

An example in use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('id');
if(!visible(element, 50)){
    element.focus();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `window.outerHeight` is cross browser?

Comment: I get `TypeError: a is null` when I try it in Firefox.

Comment: worked in chrome, firefox, opera and IE8. I suppose if you're concerned about users that use <IE8 you could research and look for a substitute. Me personally I really doubt anyone uses those browsers at all, and even if there's someone that does he deserves stuff to be not working `:D`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I tested this in the browsers I mentioned and it worked, however now I looked at the code and found the mistake.

Comment: The issue is with `.tagName`. It's all caps in my browsers, e.g. `'BODY'`. (I tried in Firefox and Chrome.) Are you on a Mac? This will fix it: `while(a.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {`

Comment: I'm on windows, this is strange because to me it's not catching any errors or misbehavior. But hey, that's the world of internet programming! Thank you I'll add this to the code!

Comment: Well, is `.tagName` all caps for you?

Comment: Appears not to be. Which is strange because in the site I fetched that little loop it was also written with capital letters and it didn't work for me until I changed them.

Comment: In HTML documents, `.tagName` returns an all caps value. In XHTML documents, it returns the case from the source code. You must be using an XHTML doctype. Info is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName

Comment: There was also another mistake. Not all elements have the outerHeight property, changed to offsetHeight

Comment: If an element is only partially in view, should it return `true` or `false`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Well the way it is built now it must be fully visible otherwise it will return false

Comment: Hm, so if 299 of 300 vertical pixels are visible, it still counts as not visible. It would be more useful if the return value somehow indicated how much of the element is visible.

Comment: You can easily change that by modifying the zero in `b > 0` to what ever your tolerance is. I'll just add this as well `:P`